# How breakpoints are calculated?

Tags: might-and-magic-duel-of-champions

I won 2/3 games on a Swiss tournament but in the end I finished fourth because I have less breakpoints than the other players.

What are breakpoints and how are they calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the explanation on this [site](http://mmdocking.com/swiss-tournament-faq/):

> **How did i earn breakpoints?**
>
> Your breakpoints are really easy to calculate.
>
> *score of your first opponent + final score of your second opponent +
>   score of your third opponent*
>
> For example: Your first opponent has in the end a 1:2, your second
>   opponent a 2:1 and your last opponent a 3:0 record. That would mean
>   you have 7 (1 win, 2 loses = score 7) + 11 (2 wins, 1 lose = score 11)
>   + 15 (3 wins = score 15) = 28 breakpoints.
>
> That means, if your opponents are showing a good performance in their
>   other 2 games, you are earning more breakpoints. If your opponents are
>   leaving the tournament after the game against you or if they are just
>   losing their games, your chance to get the second place is really low.